# mounting a file system automatically on system boot in /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, centos

How do I edit the /etc/fstab file so that the file systems on my disk partitions are automatically mounted on system boot? I'm using CentOS 5 on a VMWare virtual machine. Using an example fstab file, if it looked like this:

```
/dev/hda2   /               ext2    defaults               1 1
/dev/hdb1   /home           ext2    defaults               1 2
/dev/cdrom  /media/cdrom    auto    ro,noauto,user,exec    0 0
/dev/fd0    /media/floppy   auto    rw,noauto,user,sync    0 0
proc        /proc           proc    defaults               0 0
/dev/hda1   swap            swap    pri=42                 0 0
```

and I wanted to add another partition /dev/hdc1, with file system jfs so that it automatically mounts on system boot, how would I add it to fstab?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

/dev/hdc1   /            jfs     defaults                 0 0

well, if you need fine grain optins, read here  http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-nfs-fstab.html

Comment: Ok thanks! Was wondering if it was something I added below or if I edited something that was already there.